# Are there two separate "coming" (parousia, 3952) events?

Tags: matthew, 1-thessalonians, second-coming

1Th 4:15-17 describes "the coming (parousia, 3952) of the Lord" v15 "Himself with the voice of an archangel and with the trumpet of God." v16 And the dead and alive "shall be caught up together "in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air." Followed by 1Th 3:13b "...before our God and Father at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ with all His saints."

Matt 24:30, 31 describes the coming (parousia, 3952) of the Son of Man to earth. 30 "Then the sign of the Son of Man will appear (phaino, 5316) in heaven, and then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and they will see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven with power and great glory. 31 And He will send His angels with a great sound of a trumpet and they gather to gather His elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other."

Comment: Why would you think that?  Two raptures?

Comment: Please don't put Strong's numbers for every single word - that is not helpful and it makes your posts almost impossible to read. You can include the Greek word (and the Strong's number if you really want to) for only the most significant words for your question.

Comment: It's not clear what prompted this question. Many things are described in different ways in multiple books of the Bible. What specifically in these passages is making you think there could be two separate comings? Please [edit] to explain in detail.

Comment: Cutiousdannii - The first coming is in the air where dead and alive believers are "caught up" to meet the "Lord" (himself) in the air and are then taken by Him to the Father. See Rev 7:9. The 2nd coming is after the tribulation and the "Son of Man" (with His angels) come to earth to first reap unbelievers and then gather the surviving tribulation believers

Comment: Dottard - Not 2 raptures, two comings. One in the air where believers meet the "Lord" (Himself) in the air where He then takes them to "stand before he Throne" Rev 7:6. The 2nd as "the Son of Man" (with His angels) come to the earth to first "reap" unbelievers and then gather living tribulation believers

Answer (score 1):

It’s very likely & possible that 1 Thessalonians 4 (the so called rapture passage) is summed up in Matthew:

“And then the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven, and then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and they will see the Son of Man arriving on the clouds of heaven with power and great glory.

And he will send out his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect together from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other end of it.”  <—(Insert 1 Thessalonians 4:13-18 here)
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭24:30-31‬

If not, then you are left with 2 raptures.  Which I find to be unbiblical & wanting.

God’s Word says Jesus will only appear a second time:

“so Christ was offered once to bear the sins of many. To those who eagerly wait for Him He will appear a second time, apart from sin, for salvation.”
‭‭Hebrews‬ ‭9:28‬

Comment: Cork88 - I respectfully disagree that 1Th4:15-17 equates to Matt 24:29, 30. 1TH4:15-17, 1Th 3:13b have the "lord" meeting believers in the air and then taking them to his father. Rev 6:9 The key is "Himself", NOT angels. There are two comings not two raptures. Please note 1Th4: 15-7  is about "hearing" (shout, voice, trumpet), Matt 24: 29, 30 is about "appear" and "see".

Comment: @hank you can disagree & have a different perspective, I don’t mind.  However, scripture never says Christ will appear or come 3 times.  As if, 1.) Christ came in the flesh, 2.) Christ will secretly return again for rapture/resurrection, & then 3.) Christ will do another trumpet call to gather His elect at the Second Visible Coming of Christ.  There are books on this subject which explore the 3 views of the rapture, let me know if you want a link for that book to aid you in your overall study.  ;)

Comment: Cork88 - As I read 1Th4:15-17 there is no mention of "the Lord" v15 appearing or of believers/unbelievers) seeing - only hearing i.e., shout, voice, trumpet. But after the tribulation v29 "...the Son of Man will appear"..."and they will see the Son of Man" v30 coming to earth (both believers and unbelievers).